# how to search mysql DATE and return result together with date and the data?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I would like to know how to perform a date search and return the result?

I made a form for user to key in the date manually

```
<form  method="post" action="result.php"  id="searchform"> 
<input  type="text" name="dob" /> 
<input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
```

Also, already include the mysql connection in search.php

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mama';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);

$userDate = $_POST['dob'];
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userDate);
$myFormat = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');

$sql = "SELECT dob FROM data WHERE dob = :date";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array('date'=>$myFormat)); //Switched to array() syntax.
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
foreach($results->query($sql) as $row)
{
    print $row['rowone'] . "  ";
    print $row['rowtwo'] . "  ";
    print $row['rowthree'] . "  ";
    print "$userDate";
}
```

The user will be key in date as per asian format --> DD/MM/YYYY but i understand that mysql DATE store as Y-m-d, the date row have another three row name (row1,row2,row3) that store data.

What I need is, when the user enter the date in asian format, hit the search button, it will look for the date in mysql and return the date back together with other three row data.

Besides that, there will be only one date for one row of data.

Please advise, as I look at google, I couldn't find the most similar tutorial to perform as what I want.

Comment: At least after asking question, reply to ppl who spend time 4 u, and appreciate them by vote up and accepting answer. hope u get what u r looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can convert your user formatted date to the right format for MySQL.

```
$userDate = '27/12/2013';
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userDate);
$myFormat = $dateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

Then you can use that new variable in your query.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myDate = :date";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute(array('date'=>$myFormat)); //Switched to array() syntax.
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but there were few errors, Im using phpDesigner and this line of code `$sth->execute(['date'=>$myFormat]);` it shows syntax error unexpected [) while i try the code it also return error `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\jeff\search.php on line 6` by the way i change the `$userDate = '27/12/2013';` to `$userDate = $_POST['dob'];` as per my form

Comment: For the first error, you must be using an older version of PHP, you'll need to switch it to the array() syntax. 
For the second, see my edit - change the y in createFromFormat line to Y.

Comment: sorry I'm abit blur here. also here is another error that came out `Notice: Undefined variable: dbh in C:\xampp\htdocs\jeff\search.php on line 9`

Comment: Well you're going to have to use your own database variable. This was an example, not meant to be just copy-and-paste. You need to understand the code, not just paste it. Your code indicates you're using mysql, which is deprecated. I have shown you how to do the query in PDO. You should pick from PDO or MySQLi, since mysql should not be used in new code.

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation, but somehow i have problem to display the result.. please advise. i've updated the first post with recent code

Comment: All you're selecting is the `dob` field. 
I suggest at this point you look for basic tutorials, we are not a debugging service.